# How to match numbers that contain at least 7 different digits?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex pattern that matches any number that it's non-repeated digits are more than 7 digits.
for example it has to match:

```
1234567
122345678
```

But not to match:

```
1222345
```

non-repeating digits in this number for example `122345678` is `8` while the whole number has `9`. but the non-repeating digits in this number: `11111222345` is only `5`.
this pattern doesn't do it:

```
/[0-9]{7,}/
```

I want it to count the non-repeating digits, not to ignore any number that has repeating digits.

Comment: Just change `[A-Za-z]` in the accepted answer to `\d`

Comment: Is `12134567` valid? If so, try eg: [`count(array_unique(str_split($d))) >= 7`](https://3v4l.org/MRYWQ)

Comment: @bobblebubble thank you, it does it but I need to perform this in a string that has texts in it, meaning I want to use the pattern to extract those numbers from a mixed string.

Comment: @bobblebubble ```12134567``` is valid.

Comment: @MohammadAminGhaseminia How about using `preg_match_all()` with `\b\d{7,}\b` to extract all digits and do the other check.

Comment: Please don't change your question after others have already answered.

Comment: I understood the question as you want to match numbers composed of at least 7 unique digits eg: `712111345446` is valid or even `49833376543`. Correct me, if I'm wrong. If I'm right, the word "repeating" can lead to confusion :p

Comment: @bobblebubble it's correct, tell me what word I have to use then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The question is not very clear but this is not a dup. They want to match numbers that contain at least 7 different digits, so `1122334455667788` is valid even if it contains duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand your question is, that you want to extract numbers composed of at least 7 different digits. Would use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get the numbers in combination with a simple non-regex check:

```
if(preg_match_all('~\d{7,}~', $str, $out) > 0)
{
  $res = array_filter($out[0], function($v) {
    return count(array_unique(str_split($v))) >= 7;
  });
}
```

[See this demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EMpNP)

The word "repeating" surely lead to confusion. Also "more than 7 digits" which would be at least 8.

Comment: array_unique removes duplicates and keep 1 element. Try with `$str = '122334455667789';` it should be invalid because there is only 3 non duplicate (i.e. 1, 8, 9) but your code gives valid with 9 unique

Comment: @Toto I think OP wants the unique digits of number to be at least 7. So in your example `122334455667789` there is 9 different digits which is more than 7.

Comment: My previous comment has been deleted. I said: you're probably right